# Separate file for element locators in BDD+Cucumber+watir framework

Tags: cucumber, pom.xml, bdd, watir

I am using BDD+cucumber+watir framework to automate a website. Folder structure is like this.

[image]

Is it possible to maintain all the element Ids(locators)of a page in one file and call it in step definition.

Comment: You can - eg creating a class, module, constant, etc. Alternatively, you might want to consider using a page-object pattern.

Comment: Absolutely possible. It would be hybrid framework approach.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the structuring picture but You can either use the **PageFactory model** structuring for pure POM. If you are used to BDD and want to maintain most part of its features. You can as well store all the element ids to a file called `cucumber.yml`. You can find the page object gem https://github.com/cheezy/page-object

Create a file called `cucumber.yml` in your project directory and have all the locators stored in it as like:

`LoginPage
  emailtextfield: email_text_field_id`

You can load this pageelements.yml file using the YAML loader and call this element locator in the stepdefinition like `LoginPage[emailtextfield]`

Similarly you can categorize this for all the pages, different yml files. This would be a keydriver approach.